Using @google-cloud/pubsub with typescript
Here is REPO with example of this code. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ts-sandbox-forked-rl523r
I am trying to find the correct interfaces for published message and for received in HTTP cloud function/server
Here is my code for publish messages
import { Message, PubSub, Subscription, Topic } from '@google-cloud/pubsub'
import { MessageOptions } from '@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/topic' // I don't like this import. I expect to import this type from '@google-cloud/pubsub'

export const instance = new PubSub()
export const psaWorkerTopic = instance.topic(
  MAIN.PSA_WORKER_PUBSUB_TOPIC_NAME,
  {
    batching: PUBSUB_MAX_BATCHING,
    messageOrdering: true,
  }
)

export const publishPsaQueueMessage = async (
  data: PubSubPsaQueue,
  orderingKey?: string
) => {
  try {
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data))
    const message: MessageOptions = {
      data: dataBuffer,
      orderingKey,
    }

    const messageId = await psaWorkerTopic.publishMessage(message)
    logger.log(
      `PubSub::PSA::PUBLISHED::msgId: ${messageId}::batchId: ${data.batchId}::orderKey: ${orderingKey}`,
      {
        partnerId: data.partnerId,
        orderingKey,
      }
    )

    return messageId
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('PubSub::PSA::Could not publish message: ', e)
    if (orderingKey) psaWorkerTopic.resumePublishing(orderingKey)
    throw e
  }
}

here is the code for receiving messages
export const handleMessage = async (messageBody: {
  message: {
    data: string
    messageId: string
    publishTime: string
    attributes?: Record<string, string>
    orderingKey?: string
  }
  subscription: string
}): Promise<void> => {
  const { message } = messageBody

  const startTime = Date.now()
  const payloadDataStr = Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString('utf8')
  if (!isValidJSONString(payloadDataStr)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid Json: ${payloadDataStr}`)
  }

  const payloadData: PubSubPsaQueue = JSON.parse(payloadDataStr)

  logger.debug(
    `PubSub::PSA::START::msgId: ${message.messageId}::batchId: ${payloadData.batchId}::orderKey: ${message.orderingKey}::time: ${message.publishTime}::Received payload`,
    payloadDataStr
  )
}

export const psaSubscriptionListener = () => {
  psaWorkerSubscription.on('message', handleMessage)
  psaWorkerSubscription.on('error', (err) => {
    logger.error('PubSub::PSA::Unexpected error with GCP subscription:', err)
  })
}

And now I see ts error on this line psaWorkerSubscription.on('message', handleMessage) on handleMessage function
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type
(messageBody: {     message: {         data: string;         messageId: string;         publishTime: string;         attributes?: Record<string, string>;         orderingKey?: string;     };     subscription: string; }) => Promise<void>
is not assignable to parameter of type void
subscription.d.ts(68, 5): The last overload is declared here.

Here is example of real data which I receive on test server


What is psaWorkerSubscription?

Just updated the code. Also I put it in sandbox to be easier to debug
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ts-sandbox-forked-rl523r

It looks like you are conflating push subscriptions (typically used when triggering a Cloud Function) and pull subscriptions with code that is trying to handle both types. The code in your psaSubscriptionListener function is using the Pub/Sub client library to initiate a streaming pull connection to try to receive messages, which would get processed via the handleMessage function. Your main.post method is expecting a request to come in and trying to call handleMessage on that directly. If you are trying to handle all messages on a single subscription, you should only be doing one of these two things.
For a pull-based subscription using the client library, handleMessage is incorrect. It should be defined as:
export const handleMessage = async (message: Message): Promise<void> => {

  const startTime = Date.now();
  const payloadDataStr = message.data.toString("utf8");

  const payloadData: Record<string, unknown> = JSON.parse(payloadDataStr);

  console.debug(
    `PubSub::PSA::START::msgId: ${message.id}::batchId: ${payloadData.batchId}::orderKey: ${message.orderingKey}::time: ${message.publishTime}::Received payload`,
    payloadDataStr
  );
};

